# Applying date filter on a char-field that stores the date-time in string in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this field on a model X:

```py
class Details(models.Model):
     start_time = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now, one problem arises that I need to apply the date filter on this. is there any way to solve this.

Now due to this the datetime is getting stored like this is db

```py
Start time

2021-12-03T13:00:00Z
```

I want to do something like this-

```
Details.objects.filter(start_time__time=some_time)
```

Comment: What is your exact issue?

Comment: The start_time field is in char field and I want to filter the objects from Details model based on a date

Comment: Why not change it into a DateTimeField and convert the char one in a migration?

Comment: can't do , there is so much dependency on that field in other projects, so I gotta generate a pseudo datefield from those value and do the filtering